# Does std:: library of c++ have .cpp files?

Tags: c++, std, header-files

This may be a naive question since I'm a c++ beginner.

In a typical cpp project, we have cpp files and their header files. So based on my understanding, usually cpp files have definitions, while respective header files have  declarations. During compiling, we have to include very cpp files in the project since header files do not specify the location of the definition of the declared object. Finally, linker links declaration and definition. This allows the communication between different translation units.

However, when it comes to std:: library, we do include header files but never compile its cpp files. For example, we write #include  in main.cpp, but when compiling, the command does not have anything like g++ vector.cpp main.cpp ...

I even tried to search cpp files in the std library folder in my system, but all I can find is various header files.

I do know the definition and declaration can be included in a single header file, I don't think this is how std:: is wrote. Otherwise, it will result in multiple copies of definition when included in different cpp files.

Please help me to understand how this works? Can I do something like this with my own project?

Comment: Ofcourse there are implementation files. For example, in most IDEs by right clicking you can see the implementation for different things.

Comment: Not all of the standard library is suitable for, or can be implemented in header files. So the driver program (e.g. `g++` when using GCC) will *link* with a specific library when it creates the executable program.

Comment: Many parts of the standard library are templates and therefore compiled when being used. Some parts are simply part of an library that gets linked by default...

Comment: The other thing you can do to find the implementation is going through the definition of specific functions. If you are using VC++ pressing `F12` will take you to the implementation, on Xcode `Cmd + Ctrl + Click`. Also, I don't think the C++ standard defines whether the implementations should be in header/cpp file, so it's most likely implementation dependent

Comment: Imagine you gave two people a copy of the C++ standard, and asked them to implement something that behaves like the standard library that will be shipped with a particular toolchain targeting a particular operating system. What are the chances that (1) both people will use the same set of source files  or (2) that the code will be organised in the same way between headers or source files? [The standards mandate none of this]. Now, consider the fact that implementations of the standard library accompany different compilers that are implemented differently, and target different operating systems

Comment: Here is a set of .cpp files belonging to one standard library: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/tree/main/stl/src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is compiled code in the standard library. You don't have to compile it because the library comes already compiled with your compiler. And you don't explicitly link to it, because the compiler knows about it. So you don't see it mentioned anywhere when you do normal builds. If you set your compiler to some form of verbose mode you can see that the name of the standard library gets passed to the linker, which pulls the code it needs from the library.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to templated libraries, the source code must be found in the header files (.h or .hpp), so it is not exceptional to find header-only libraries.

If part of the code is not templated and its implementation is made in source files (.cpp), usually the code is precompiled and supplied as .lib (.a/.so) files to be linked to.

As regards open source APIs, if there are .cpp files they are delivered as well and you have to compile/precompile them by yourself.

Comment: Not all compilers require templates to be defined inline within header files, directly or indirectly.   An implementation of the standard library is often tied very closely to a particular compiler (or compiler version) and may exploit various forms of "compiler magic" in different ways,

Comment: @Peter: in this case, some implementation files must be provided anyway otherwise code generation is impossible. (I exclude the case of explicit template specializations and of precompiled headers.)